# How to prove the sum of this series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

I have the sum of this series

$\sum_{n=3,5,7,...}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{(n^2-1)^2}\right)$

with numerical values, I can see that the sum reaches $0.0.0181168$ (see below), but I have a hard time proving this mathematically.

Appreciate any help to prove this.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:
This is
$$\sum_1^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{(2n+1)^2 -1} \right)^2 \\ =\frac{1}{16}\sum_1^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{n(n+1)}\right)^2 \\ =\frac{1}{16} \sum_1^{\infty} \left( \frac 1n -\frac{1}{n+1} \right)^2 \\ =\frac{1}{16} \left( \sum_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} +\sum_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n+1)^2} -2\sum_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(n+1)} \right) $$

For the first two sums, use the fact that $$\sum_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} =\frac{\pi^2}{6} $$ The third sum is telescoping after using partial fractions. You should get $\frac{\pi^2 -9}{48}$ which matches your result.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks